# File not deleting with if statement even if it is true, but is deleting without if statement

Tags: java

Whenever I add the:

`if(lines[0].equalsIgnoreCase("owner: " + sender.getName()))`

The file does not delete, but yet this:

`System.out.println("Deleted message successfully!");`

still runs, meaning the if statement is true.

Whenever I delete the if statement above, it does delete the file.

Here is the code: (not the best)

```
String lines[], strLine;
int a = 0;
String fileLoc = currentDir + "//plugins//ExtendedSigns//" + c[1] + ".txt";
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(fileLoc)));
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileLoc);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
lines = new String[1 + lnr.getLineNumber()];
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
    lines[a] = strLine;
    a++;
}
if(lines[0].equalsIgnoreCase("owner: " + sender.getName()))
{
    File del = new File(currentDir + "//plugins//ExtendedSigns//" + c[1] + ".txt");
    del.delete();
    System.out.println("Deleted message successfully!");

}
else
{
    System.out.println("Deleted message unsuccessfully! You do not own it!");
}
```

Comment: delete returns a boolean indicating if the file was actually deleted. As to why not, don't know--are you in the directory you think you are when you run it? Do you have permissions? What are those extra forward-slashes for?

Comment: why do you thing you need all the double `/` in the paths for?

Comment: I can delete the file manauly (right click > deleted) and when the if(lines[0].equalsIgnoreCase("owner: " + sender.getName())) is not there. Since it deletes without if statement, the directory must be right. Is there a way to 'force' delete it?

Comment: Don't you need double slashes for paths? It the way I have always done them...

Comment: What system are you on? Windows? Linux? Mac OS X?

Comment: Perhaps your file is not closed? Before comparison, call br.close() so that file gets closed (and linenumberreader should also get closed).

Comment: That did work, Thank you! I still wonder why it would delete if the if statement was gone....

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
if(del.delete()) System.out.println("Deleted message successfully!");
else System.out.println("Deleted message unsuccessfully! You do not own it!");
```

Comment: The problem is that it delete without the if(lines[0].equalsIgnoreCase("owner: " + sender.getName())) there. but with it, it does not delete

Comment: @matt Then you can assume that `lines[0]` does not equal `"owner: " + sender.getName()`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your file is not closed? Before comparison, call br.close() so that file gets closed (and linenumberreader should also get closed). Probably without your if/else statement, the JVM is closing the files or it is not locked anymore. May be something to do with `sender`.